# pdftk stamp is stripping links

Tags: linux, pdf, hyperlink, pdftk

I'm trying to stamp one PDF file (multiple pages) with another (single page) PDF file by using `pdftk` stamp operation.

```
    pdftk large.pdf stamp stamp.pdf output stamped.pdf
```

Now, `stamp.pdf` contains a single page with a single line of text at the bottom of the page. That text is a hyperlink (that is, a pdfmark link annotation is located above that line of text). Newly created `stamped.pdf` is properly stamped but hyperlink is not present anymore - it seems that `stamp` operation (and `multistamp`, and also `background` and `multibackground` operations) is, for some reason (?), stripping this hyperlink annotation.

Does anyone know how to circumvent this?

---

I've tried this on multiple distros and results are the same (Debian 6.0, Ubuntu 12.04, CentOS 6.4 - `pdftk` versions 1.44 and 1.41).

Please note that hyperlinks in `large.pdf` are preserved in output `stamped.pdf`.

Solution like converting `large.pdf` to PS and then adding links to each page in PS and then converting back to PDF is not an option as that takes a really long time compared to `pdftk` stamping (in my case it takes something like 10-20 seconds - depending on `large.pdf` size, while `pdftk` completes stamping in 1 second).

I'm also interested in any other Linux command-line based tool for stamping one PDF with another PDF (or PS).

Thanks.

---

**EDIT**

I tested with latest version of pdftk (2.02) and the results are the same - links are stripped.

I tested stamping functionality with some other (non-free) tools as well - Coherent PDF and VeryPDF - both are stripping links. So, I guess it's either something that is overlooked or there is some technical difficulty in maintaining hyperlink annotations in stamping PDF.

Comment: That is not really a programming related question, is it?

Comment: Well, I'm currently writing PHP application that utilizes pdftk (among other things) to stamp PDFs. So, my inclination was to post a question  here - although, technically, I guess you are right. Should I "move" this to i.e. superuser?

Answer (score 0):

Appearantly you can't do it that way. 
This answers the question why: "Stamp PDFs" are flattened and stripped, so all extra information is lost.

Source http://forum.planetpdf.com/wb/default.asp?action=9&fid=103&read=58551

Comment: Interesting read. Post also hints how one would go about adding hyperlink annotations using libraries that pdftk uses (PdfStamper).

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible for a program to combine both sets of hyperlinks, but as you've noticed, pdftk doesn't do that, and neither do the Coherent PDF tools (which I wrote).

You can add a bug report here, and we will put it on the list of things to do:

[cpdf bug reports](https://github.com/johnwhitington/cpdflib-source)

There are lots of things to combine when stamping: fonts and resources need to be renamed so as not to clash, bookmarks need to be merged, etc. Some tools do all of this, some just a little, and some just the minimum.

Maybe you could find a tool which can add a hyperlink given a URL and a rectangle, and then do it after the stamping?

Comment: I've searched for the tool to add hyperlink annotations after the stamping - unfortunately nothing found so far.
Btw., the link for your project on Github is wrong - should be [this](https://github.com/johnwhitington/cpdf-source). Will fill a bug report there.
Thanks.
I'm also now thinking of trying my luck on adding the feature myself - either to your cpdf or pdftk.

Comment: The closest I know is CTAN `pax` package: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pax?lang=en - that seems to be unmaintained, though.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `stamp` I managed to keep links working with `background`.
In fact if you look the docs for `stamp` (https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-man-page/#dest-op-stamp) it says: `This behaves just like the background operation except it overlays the stamp PDF page on top of the input PDF document’s pages` so the overlay is the problem.
`background` instead put the pdf in the background preserving the original pdf (https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-man-page/#dest-op-background)